# How to call a function on PayUMoney Bolt Launch?

Tags: javascript, php, payumoney, payu

We are using PayUMoney Bolt into website.

We have integrated PHP Kit provided by PayUMoney (Screenshot added). I need to add CSS on Bolt Launch.

Bolt popup loads into iframe so I am not able to write CSS for iframe content. I have to add CSS using javascript after Bolt popup load.

```
bolt.launch({
       key: $('#pkey').val(),
       txnid: $('#txnid').val(), 
       hash: h,
       amount: $('#payu_amt').val(),
       firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
       email: $('#payu_email').val(),
       phone: parseInt(''),
       productinfo: $('#productinfo').val(),
       surl : $('#surl').val(),
       furl: $('#furl').val(),
       mode: 'dropout' 
   },{ responseHandler: function(BOLT){
       alert( BOLT.response.txnStatus );     
   },
       catchException: function(BOLT){
           alert(BOLT.message );
       }
   });
```

[Payumoney PHP script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxsdN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to call a javascript function after bolt launch to add css PayUMoney Payment Popup. Because it is showing horizontal scroll on mobile.